# selector ID and functions: why dont work?

Tags: jquery

selector ID and functions: why don't work?

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="textUpload" >
<input type="text" id="textUpload2" value="" />
```

JS:

```
$("input").mouseover(function(){
  alert('111');
 });

$("input#textUpload").mouseover(function(){
  alert('222');
});

$("#textUpload").mouseover(function(){
  alert('333');
});

$("#textUpload").click(function(){
  alert('444');
});

$("#textUpload").on('click', function(event) {
  alert('555');
});
```

Work only '111' option. Why?

http://jsfiddle.net/nywuctuk/rw9t1pxL/17/

Comment: Did you read selector section in jQuery manual?

Comment: Pro Tip: Debug with `console.log`, not `alert`.

Comment: Works here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/L133beu2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appears to be a strange character between `type="text"` and `id="`. It looks like a space but isn't. Removing this and replacing with a space fixes your code. (Edit: Chrome inspector shows it to be a `&nbsp;`)

The reason the first selector works, I assume, is because it is the only one that selects by type and not ID. Therefore it is unaffected by the malformed attributes.

```js
  
$("#textUpload").mouseover(function(){
  //alert('111');
  $(document.body).append('<br> 111');
 });

$("input#textUpload").mouseover(function(){
  //alert('222');
  $(document.body).append('<br> 222');
});

$("#textUpload").mouseover(function(){
  //alert('333');
  $(document.body).append('<br> 333');
});

$("#textUpload").click(function(){
  //alert('444');
  $(document.body).append('<br> 444');
});

$("#textUpload").on('click', function(event) {
  //alert('555');
  $(document.body).append('<br> 555');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="textUpload">
<input type="text" id="textUpload2" value="" />
```

[Edited JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rw9t1pxL/19/)

Comment: validator dont see it on my webpage =(

Comment: can we find out more infortation about this symbol?

Comment: If you use your browsers dev tools to inspect the character you can see it is a HTML non-breaking space(`&nbsp;`)